# arising from a use of `Control.Exception.catch'

Tags: haskell

When i load a haskell file, it has error

```
module REPL(REPL(..), repl) where
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import System.Console.Readline(readline, addHistory)

data REPL s = REPL {
    repl_init :: IO (String, s),        -- prompt and initial state
    repl_eval :: s -> String -> IO (Bool, s),       -- quit flag and new state
    repl_exit :: s -> IO ()
    }

repl :: REPL s -> IO ()
repl p = do
    (prompt, state) <- repl_init p
    let loop s = (do
        mline <- readline prompt
        case mline of
        Nothing -> loop s
        Just line -> do
            (quit, s') <- repl_eval p s line
            if quit then
            repl_exit p s'
             else do
            addHistory line
            loop s'
        ) E.catch undefined (\(e :: E.SomeException) -> putStrLn "Handled exception!"
        )
    loop state

REPL.hs:21:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO (Maybe String)'
           against inferred type `t -> Maybe String'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: mline <- readline prompt
    In the expression:
        (do { mline <- readline prompt;
              case mline of {
                Nothing -> loop s
                Just line
                  -> do { (quit, s') <- repl_eval p s line;
                          .... } } })
          E.catch
          undefined
          (\ (e :: E.SomeException) -> putStrLn "Handled exception!")
    In the definition of `loop':
        loop s = (do { mline <- readline prompt;
                       case mline of {
                         Nothing -> loop s
                         Just line -> do { ... } } })
                   E.catch
                   undefined
                   (\ (e :: E.SomeException) -> putStrLn "Handled exception!")
```

Comment: Please include the code that's generating the error.

Comment: Further to the above, if your code is long then edit it down so that it is short and still exhibits the error, but does not include code unrelated to your problem. Sometimes this process allows you to solve your problem without help, otherwise it makes it easier for other people to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use scoped type variables by including this line at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

Or in a GHCi session just do:

```
> :set -XScopedTypeVariables
```

And in your catch function provide a signature.  In GHCi:

```
> import Control.Exception as E
> E.catch undefined (\(e :: E.SomeException) -> putStrLn "Handled exception!")
Handled exception!
```

Celebrate good times, come on!

Comment: I will try it tonight at home, feedback you later

Comment: I posted the code and add {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
 and type :set -XScopedTypeVariables before :load, it has imported control exception, still get error

Comment: @MFLD  You didn't even try my answer, which works on your code.  See the line with your handler?   Use an explicit type signature: `) `Control.Exception.catch` ( \(exc::Control.Exception.SomeException) ->`

Comment: I get it, just use catch instead of Control.Exception.catch and use this \(e :: SomeException) , i will try it tonight, feedback you later

Comment: I am a starter, after replace with your code, compiler write another error

Answer (score 2):

It would help to see the actual code that's giving you trouble, but please see the below for an example of the problem you describe and solution to the example by adding a type signature.  In ghci:

```
> :m + Control.Exception
> print "hello world" `Control.Exception.catch` (\_ -> print "goodby world")

<interactive>:1:21:
    Ambiguous type variable `e' in the constraint:
      (Exception e) arising from a use of `Control.Exception.catch'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression:
        print "hello world"
      `Control.Exception.catch`
        (\ _ -> print "goodby world")
    In an equation for `it':
        it
          = print "hello world"
          `Control.Exception.catch`
            (\ _ -> print "goodby world")
> print "hello world" `Control.Exception.catch` ((\_ -> print "goodby world") :: IOException -> IO ())
"hello world"
```

The point is that the catch expression `(\_ -> print "goodby world")` doesn't constrain the type of its argument.  I expect you're have a similar problem.

Comment: As i am using an existing software, the code is long, if above method not work, i check and reply you tonight

Comment: Fortunately, the code is short, i posted. Please see why load error